# Multiple imputation - original model

Tags: multiple-imputation

I have a question. I have a dataset with some missing values that were not MCAR. I imputed them with fully conditional specification method iterations. I then executed my analysis on the basis of the imputed dataset. The results of the original model (with missing values: listwise deletion)  did not change much in the eventual pooled model. My idea would be to go back the missing values dataset. What do you think?

Comment: I mean running my analysis with the missing value dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the choice depends on the audience that will read whatever you write.

If they are mostly statistically unsophisticated, I'd say you could use the original data set and put a footnote about how multiple imputation did not change things much. If they are more sophisticated, I'd go with the MI analysis. Even if things don't change "much" they change *some* and the MI is a better approach.

Also, be careful that you looked at *all* the output for what changed (or didn't). Not just parameter estimates but their standard errors (or whatever your analysis involves - you didn't say what analysis you did, so it's hard to say what might be affected).

Comment: Thanks. I'm doing a multilevel logistic analysis with 5 imputed datasets and I'm going to combine them manually in a pooled version